# QT5.5 QSound isFinshed

Tags: c++, qt5.5, qtmultimedia

I am busy making a reverb algorithm. While working with `QSound` I found a few problems.

First, the sound doesn't play while trying the `QSound::play()` like this:

```
/// Play output .wav file.
QSound sound("C:/Users/mvdelft/Documents/Reverb_configurator/output.wav", this);
sound.play();
```

It only plays the sound if I give the path againt with the `QSound::play` (`QString` file) like this:

```
/// Play output .wav file.
QSound sound("C:/Users/mvdelft/Documents/Reverb_configurator/output.wav", this);
sound.play("C:/Users/mvdelft/Documents/Reverb_configurator/output.wav");
```

A related problem I have has to do with the function `bool QSound::isFinshed()` which doesn't work for me. Code:

```
 /// Play output .wav file.
QSound sound("C:/Users/mvdelft/Documents/Reverb_configurator/output.wav", this);
sound.play("C:/Users/mvdelft/Documents/Reverb_configurator/output.wav");
sound.setLoops(10);

/// Check is sound is finished
while (!sound.isFinished()){}

ui->listWidget->addItem("Finished playing sound");
}/// End of scope
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version, you create a `QSound` object on stack with a file, start playing it, and immediately destroy it. This will stop the sound playing, so you won't hear anything.

In the second version, `QSound::play(const QString &)` is a static method. It will play the sound in the background. That's why you hear something. 
With the static method, the calls to `setLoops` and `isFinished` will not work. Also, the busy loop (`while (!sound.isFinished()) ;`) is very bad, as it will consume 100% CPU, and probably block playing the sound.

For the sound to work, you should create it on the heap, and regulary check the `isFinished()` on a timer event. However, I suggest [`QSoundEffect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsoundeffect.html), as it gives you more control. Most importantly, the `playingChanged()` signal, that will inform you when the playing has finished without the need to constantly check.

Outline:

```
void MyObject::playSomeSound() {
   QSoundEffect *s = new QSoundEffect(this);
   connect(s, SIGNAL(playingChanged()), this, SLOT(soundPlayingChanged()));
   s->setSource("C:/Users/mvdelft/Documents/Reverb_configurator/output.wav");
   s->setLoopCount(10);
   s->play();
}

void MyObject::soundPlayingChanged() {
   QSoundEffect *s = qobject_cast<QSoundEffect *> (sender());
   // Will also be called when playing was started, so check if really finished
   if (!s->isPlaying()) {
      s->deleteLater();

      // Do what you need to do when playing finished
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment, it works now! As someone with average programmings skills it still confuses me alot with memory issues. Thanks though!